# Clear Content If a Cell Value Changes in the ActiveSheet of a workbook with many sheets

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("H59:CP61").ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

B4 is a data validation list. I want to clear the range when cell B4 changes.

I tried putting the code in "ThisWorkbook" and under "Module" section.

I want the code to run for all worksheets. Instead of copying and pasting the code for every worksheet, how can I modify the code to work in "ThisWorkbook" or under the "Module" section?

The code should only clear the contents in the activesheet where B4 changes.

Comment: Do you want each sheet's range to be cleared, or does each sheet have a data validation list, and you'd want this to run separately for each unique sheet? (In other words, does your "Sheet1" have the validation, and if B4 is changed, do you want *all sheets'* `H59:CP61` cleared? Or just that range on the sheet where `B4` changes)

Comment: For each sheet only, clear contents on the Active Sheet where B4 changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement the `Change` event on every possible worksheet, then use the `_SheetChange` event of the workbook.

Put the code here:

[image]

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("B4")) Is Nothing Then
        Sh.Range("H59:CP61").ClearContents
    End If
End Sub
```